# d3js: _on()_ doesn't send the current datum object to the onmouse function

Tags: events, d3.js, highlight, force-layout

I would like to highlight the edges of a graph when the connected nodes are hovered.
I took inspiration from the [Bundle example](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111116/bundle.html):

[image]

However the on() function is not giving the d object to the onmouse function:

```
d3.json("graph_file.json", function(json) {
      force
          .nodes(json.nodes)
          .links(json.links)
          .start();

      var link = svg.selectAll("line.link")
          .data(json.links)
        .enter().append("line")
          .attr("class", function(d) { return "link source-" + d.source.key + " target-" + d.target.key; })
          .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

      var node = svg.selectAll("circle.node")
          .data(json.nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .attr("r", function(d) { return d.connec; })
          .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
          .on("mouseover", mouseover)
          .on("mouseout", mouseout)
          .call(force.drag);
```

...

```
        function mouseover(d) {
      svg.selectAll("line.link.target-" + d.key)
          .classed("target", true);


      svg.selectAll("line.link.source-" + d.key)
          .classed("source", true);
    }
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: Is anything passed into your mouseover function? Or id d undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately I was not able to reproduce your problem! The only thing that caught me at first was when I defined my mouseover and mouseout functions after setting them in .on(...) In that case they were undefined for the call and no mouse handlers were set - so the functions were simply never called.

Anyway, you can see what I tried [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tjYTL/2). The code:

```
var w = 400,
    h = 400;
var vis = d3.select("svg").attr("width", 800).attr("height", 800);

var nodes = [];
var links = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    var node = {
        label: "node " + i,
        value: Math.random(),
        key: i
    };
    nodes.push(node);
};

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (Math.random() > .95) links.push({
            source: nodes[i],
            target: nodes[j],
            weight: Math.random()
        });
    }
};

var force = d3.layout.force().size([w, h]).nodes(nodes).links(links);

force.start();

var link = vis.selectAll("line.link").data(links).enter().append("line").style("stroke", "#CCC").attr("class", function(d) {
    return "link source-" + d.source.key + " target-" + d.target.key;
});

var mouseover = function(d) {
    txt.text(JSON.stringify(d));
    //txt.text("line.link.target-" + d.key);
    vis.selectAll("line.link.target-" + d.key).classed("target", true).style("stroke", '#F00');

    vis.selectAll("line.link.source-" + d.key).classed("source", true).style("stroke", '#F00');
}


var mouseout = function(d) {
    vis.selectAll("line.link.target-" + d.key).classed("target", false).style("stroke", "#CCC");

    vis.selectAll("line.link.source-" + d.key).classed("source", false).style("stroke", "#CCC");
}


var node = vis.selectAll("circle.node").data(force.nodes()).enter().append("circle").attr("class", "node").attr("r", 5).style("fill", function(d) {
    return d3.rgb(55 * d.value, 255 * d.value, 155 * d.value)
}).style("stroke", "#FFF").style("stroke-width", 3).on("mouseover", mouseover).on("mouseout", mouseout).call(force.drag);

var txt = vis.append('text').attr({
    transform: 'translate(5,400)'
}).text("Node Info");


var updateLink = function() {
    this.attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
    }).attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
    }).attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
    }).attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
    });
}

var updateNode = function() {
    this.attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
}

force.on("tick", function() {
    node.call(updateNode);
    link.call(updateLink);
});​
```

Comment: thanks a lot this detailled example I managed to do what i wanted. Except , how to make node label appear when hovered...

Comment: I ust noticed I double-classed the links...oops.
You should be able to add text similarly to how you add the nodes (just add an offset to the translation) but class the text more like the nodes. Then you can set their visibility the same way you set colour on the link lines.