# Show d3.layout.force link tooltip on mouse over

Tags: javascript, d3.js, hyperlink, tooltip, force-layout

How do I implement tooltips on mouse over for links in a `D3` directed graph layout? I'm adapting the `D3` force example, so setting up node tooltips was straightforward using code like this:

```
    node.append("title")
        .text(function(n) {
            return n.id;
        });
```

Trying a similar technique with the links didn't result in mouse over tool tips:

```
    var link = svg.selectAll("line.link")
        .data(json.links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
            return 4;
        });

link.append("title")
    .text(function(n) {
            return n.info;
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find different solutions suggested by Mike Bostock on this Google Groups thread ["show value when click or move mouse over on d3.svg.line"](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/d3-js/gHzOj91X2NA)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is a combination of these two answers:

[d3js: _on()_ doesn't send the current datum object to the onmouse function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053649/d3js-on-doesnt-send-the-current-datum-object-to-the-onmouse-function/13076450#13076450)

and

[Adding tooltip to bar chart generated using svg path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195540/adding-tooltip-to-bar-chart-generated-using-svg-path/13277508#13277508)

Both have jsFiddles you can play with.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the link title as shown above does result in mouse over tooltips -- iff you let the mouse hover over any portion of the link a couple of seconds.